I don't receive any data in get_clients_from_signal_server p2p chat
When I receive the list of connected users the program simply freezes and the server stops responding. It just shows the source in my terminal, but no message.
signal_server:
import socket
import threading
import json

clients = {}
lock = threading.Lock()

def handle_client(data, addr, sock):
    global clients
    try:
        message = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
        print(f"Received message from {addr}: {message}")  # Debugging statement
        if 'register' in message:
            with lock:
                clients[message['name']] = addr
            response = {'status': 'registered', 'clients': list(clients.keys())}
            sock.sendto(json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8'), addr)
            print(f"Registered {message['name']} from {addr}")  # Debugging statement
        elif 'get_clients' in message:
            response = {'status': 'registered', 'clients': list(clients.keys())}
            sock.sendto(json.dumps(response).encode('utf-8'), addr)
            print(f"Sent client list to {addr}")  # Debugging statement
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error handling client {addr}: {e}")

def signal_server(host, port):
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    print(f"Signal server started on {host}:{port}")

    while True:
        try:
            data, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(data, addr, server_socket)).start()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in main loop: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    signal_host = 'localhost'
    signal_port = 8001
    signal_server(signal_host, signal_port)

The client app code starts here and the get_clients_from_signal_server function sends a request to the server to get user data.
P2PClient:
import argparse
import socket
import sys
import time
import json
import threading

shutdown = False

class Message:
    def __init__(self, **data):
        self.status = 'online'
        for param, value in data.items():
            setattr(self, param, value)
        self.curr_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S", time.localtime())

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

class P2PClient:
    def __init__(self, host, port, name=None, signal_server_address=None):
        self.current_connection = None
        self.client_address = (host, port)
        self.name = name if name else f"{host}:{port}"
        self.signal_server_address = signal_server_address
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.socket.bind(self.client_address)

    def register_with_signal_server(self):
        if self.signal_server_address:
            message = {"register": True, "name": self.name}
            self.socket.sendto(json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'), self.signal_server_address)
            data, _ = self.socket.recvfrom(1024)
            response = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
            if response['status'] == 'registered':
                print(f"Registered with signal server. Current clients: {response['clients']}")

    def get_clients_from_signal_server(self):
        if self.signal_server_address:
            message = {"get_clients": True}
            print(f"Requesting client list from signal server at {self.signal_server_address}")  # Debugging statement
            self.socket.sendto(json.dumps(message).encode('utf-8'), self.signal_server_address)
            data, _ = self.socket.recvfrom(1024)
            response = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
            print(f"Received clients from signal server: {response['clients']}")
            return response['clients']
        return []

...


    def run(self):
        global shutdown
        self.register_with_signal_server()
        recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        recv_thread.start()
        while not shutdown:
            print("1. Get list of clients")
            print("2. Connect to client")
            print("3. Exit")
            choice = input("Choose an option: ")
            if choice == "1":
                clients = self.get_clients_from_signal_server()
                print("Available clients:")
                for client_name in clients:
                    print(f" - {client_name}")
            elif choice == "2":
                self.connect()
            elif choice == "3":
                shutdown = True
                print("Exiting...")
            else:
                print("Invalid option. Please try again.")
            time.sleep(1)
        recv_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-ho", "--host", help="p2p client host ip address, like 127.0.0.1")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--port", help="p2p client host port, like 8001")
    parser.add_argument("-sh", "--signalhost", help="signal server host ip address, like 127.0.0.1")
    parser.add_argument("-sp", "--signalport", help="signal server port, like 8000")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    try:
        host = args.host
        port = int(args.port)
        signal_host = args.signalhost
        signal_port = int(args.signalport)
        name = input("Name: ").strip()
        signal_server_address = (signal_host, signal_port)
        p2p_client = P2PClient(host, port, name=name, signal_server_address=signal_server_address)
        p2p_client.run()
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        print("Incorrect arguments values, use --help/-h for more info.")

Bat files are written here to launch users. Server is starting on localhost 8001.
python p2p_client.py --host localhost --port 8002 --signalhost localhost --signalport 8001

python p2p_client.py --host localhost --port 8003 --signalhost localhost --signalport 8001


Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

socket is "stupid" object and it doesn't care if you get all data at once or in many parts. It may need to check if recv get expected number of data and eventually loop code to get more. But this needs to send length of data before data - and this need to decide how  you send it. If you send it as  integer converted to 4 bytes then other sides has to first read 4 bytes and convert it back to integer.

it needs to run code to see problem but it raise error in recv_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive) because it can't find self.receive
